# Remove last td from table jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using a table and dynamically creating a column (td) on click jquery. I want to remove the column as the last td, but in each td one more table is coming, hence I can't remove the entire td.

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td class="myclass">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
   
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove the last td having the class name my class. I tried like this:

```
$('tr').find('td:last').remove();
```

But it's removing the last td from the inner table, I want to remove the entire last td having class myclass.

Comment: Why are you doing this horrendous thing? Nesting Tables? Surely there is a better, cleaner way to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
$('tr').find('td.myclass:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `td` with the class

```
$('tr > td.myClass:last-child').remove();
```

or if you want t remove the last one from the collection

```
$('td.myClass:last').remove();
```

Comment: I wouldn't help him further down this path. There is something wrong with his structure.

Comment: @GaryHayes :  _But its removing last td from inner table. i want to remove entire last td having class myclass_ - the above code would remove the last td with the class

Answer (score 0):

You can select specific `td` with `.myclass`

```js
$("td.myclass:last").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;First</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td class="myclass">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Last</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```